# Is keeping encrypted password in memory for later use safe?

Tags: c#, security, encryption

I am receiving username and password with which I am creating a connection to the web service and then consuming various functions using that service.

However I was thinking to storing username as plaintext and encrypted password for later auto-diagnosing purpose in which I may call a method in `catch()` which will re-initialize connection by using same username and decrypted password.

I dont have much experience in encryption and decryption but I may use methods as suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6a2836a-d587-4068-8630-94f4fb2a2aeb/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-in-c) making them `private`.

Also, of course, I will blank out temporary variables where I stored password and even the `TextBox` text.

But I want to know if keeping encrypted password in memory is safe?

Comment: It is not, the garbage collector keeps copies in memory that are out of reach.  And you cannot "blank-out" strings, they are immutable.  The reason for the SecureString class.

Comment: Use a 1-way hash instead - SHA1/SHA256.

Comment: I fear you lack background (even more than me) to do this properly. A couple notes: `private` does nothing to deter a hacker (especially if they can inspect memory at will) and even if it could hide the encryption routine this would be security through obscurity, "blanking out temporary variables" probably doesn't do what you hope it does (assuming you mean something like `string s = plaintext; ...; s = null;`), and if you keep the key available too you only minimally obstruct the attacker. Please tell me if misinterpreted something.

Comment: @delnan well u did not miss-interpreted anything but then whats the solution?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Re `TextBox`, a better option depends on a lot of internal details. There may be a widget that provides such a guarantee (for strings, there's `SecureString`), I'm not very well versed in Windows UI programming.

Comment: @Kami Hashing is good if all you need is verifying someone put in the correct password, but here the program needs to send the password itself to several third party services so *those* can verify the password for authentication. (Though bare SHA is *not* good enough for storing the password and keeping the plain text secure, at least iterate and salt it.)

Comment: @HansPassant So blanking out `TextBox` is even useless? Whats the solution then?

Answer (score 2):

You should really hash the password, not encrypt it. That is, you (and by extension, attackers) should not be able to "decrypt" the password they give you if it is hashed.

Storing a hashed password in memory is reasonable. It will have to be in memory at some point anyway.

Comment: but am anxious since will keep it in memory all time, is there other standard approach followed?

Comment: Usually people store it in the DB, but your security shouldn't revolve around how long that hashed password is in memory

Comment: @Oleksi Poking in a programs is a legitimate and sometimes extremely effective attack. The only downside is that it requires physical access to the computer, or running arbitrary code (at the right time and with enough privileges to sidestep memory protection). Minimizing the time critical data is in physical RAM minimizes the attack window, though it obviously doesn't close it.

Comment: Also, (copying my comment to someone else) hashing is good if all you need is verifying someone put in the correct password, but here the program needs to send the password itself to several third party services so those can verify the password for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure I understand your question correctly:

1. You are writing a client software
2. The user enters the password
3. You store the password in a variable for a short time to authenticate to a web service
4. You want to know whether you can store the password *in memory* (i.e. in a variable) for longer periods of time in order to authenticate to the web service again later

If these assumptions are correct: Don't worry too much about it, just keep it in a variable and that's it - preferably in a [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as suggested by Hans Passant. SecureString will do the work for you:

> the value of a SecureString object is automatically encrypted, can be modified until your application marks it as read-only, and can be deleted from computer memory by either your application or the .NET Framework garbage collector.

Hashing makes sense on the server side where the password (or the hash) is stored on disk/in a database. On the client side, you cannot hash the password since you need it to authenticate to the web service.

If you wanted to store the password permanently (i.e. write it to a file), *then* you would need to worry about encryption/hashing.